# iterate through a tuple to form a string

Tags: python, for-loop, tuples

I am trying to create a function named make_string, that uses * correctly with a parameter: strings
The function should return a string of all the values supplied joined, and separated by a space.
Outside the make_string function, I declare a variable named my_string, and assign the value returned from the make_string function.
Then I call the make_string function with the following values: "Alderaan", "Coruscant", "Dagobah", "Endor", "Hoth". Finally I print the value of my_string to the terminal...and it returns None, when it should return Alderaan Coruscant Dagobah Endor Hoth
Can anybody tell me where I am going wrong please?

```
def make_string(*strings):
    my_string = ""
    for x in strings:
        my_string = x.join(strings)
        return my_string

my_string = make_string()

make_string("Alderaan", "Coruscant", "Dagobah", "Endor", "Hoth")

print(my_string)
```

Comment: You're calling `make_string()` with no arguments, so the loop never executes, so you don't return anything.

Comment: The second call to `make_string()` has arguments and returns something, but you don't assign it to the variable.

Comment: Also, the loop won't run more than once, as you `return` from the function at the end of the first loop.

Comment: `join()` has its own loop, why did you think you needed to put that in a `for` loop?

Comment: So your code is essentially equivalent to `return strings[0].join(strings)` when there's at least one string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things going on in your code that are a little wonky.

1. You're constantly re-assigning the value of `my_string` every time you loop through `for x in strings`
2. There's no reason to start with a blank string here since you're already using `join`
3. Your function call isn't setting to `my_string` -- it isn't set to anything. What you want is like `my_string = make_string("Bob", "Mary")` etc.

This should do the trick:

```
def make_string(*strings):
    return " ".join(strings)

my_string = make_string("Alderaan", "Coruscant", "Dagobah", "Endor", "Hoth")

print(my_string)
```

Personally, I would say you don't even need a function here, especially if you can easily set what you're using for `*strings` to a variable. For example:

```
planets = ["Alderaan", "Coruscant", "Dagobah", "Endor", "Hoth"]
print(" ".join(planets))
```

Comment: ah that's brilliant, it worked! thank you!

Comment: @Jose glad it worked. if this helped, please mark it as the accepted answer (the checkmark under the vote arrows)